# Kinect Grip Gesture for Click

Tags: c#, uigesturerecognizer, kinect, gesture

I'm using kinect V2.0. I need to perform click using grip gesture. Is there a way to handle the Grip gesture in V2.0 like AddHandPointerGripHandler in V1.8.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Kinect SDK 2.0? If yes, are you coding in C#?

Comment: Yes, im using kinect SDK 2.0 and C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft Kinect SDK v2.0, the [`Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.body.aspx) class includes two properties:

- [`Body.HandRightState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.body.handrightstate.aspx)
- [`Body.HandLeftState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.body.handleftstate.aspx)

Both these properties are instances of the [`HandState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.handstate.aspx) enumeration, which specifies if the hand is:

- Closed (and you can detect this to trigger the Grip gesture);
- Lasso (which means that the hand is closed in a fist, except for a finger pointing upward)
- Not Tracked (the hand state is not tracked)
- Open (the hand is open)
- Unknown

If you want to **detect the Grip gesture**, you can use a variable to save the last hand state detected, and then a "click" can be triggered every time this variable pass **from an Open state to a Closed one**.

Obviously, all of this can be executed every time you detect a SkeletonFrame.