# Kinect v2 Grip gesture to select xaml button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect-v2

I have a problem using XAML Buttons and C# with Kinect v2. I want to draw a button with three different states, according to default/over/selected, changing according with hand gestures off/over/grip.
I've read the answer in the following post ([Kinect Grip Gesture for Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523159/kinect-grip-gesture-for-click)), but I don't know how to implement the suggesting code. I've also viewed ControlsBasics-WPF solution (from Kinect v2 SDK) but I don't want to use that code because I don't like the hand cursor suggested (I want to simply add a hand image over the tracked joint).

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried the C# code from ControlsBasics-WPF, this tutorial [link](http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/lab10/index.html) and also [link](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2091/how-to-click-a-button-and-use-a-hand-as-cursor-in-kinect). Unfortunately, all these examples create a hand cursor in a xaml KinectRegion and they doesn't support grip gesture (xaml buttons are selected by a push gesture).

Answer (score 0):

maybe another object like ListBox that works with grip gesture is better for you

Comment: For OP and future readers, could you explain why ListBox would work better?